# jqgrid image cell custom formatter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a problem where i need to show the images with some details in each and every cell of a row. 
To achieve this i used custom formatter for a cell.

[image]

The cellvalue will give image source. but what to do to get the info **Name** and **phone** in custom formatter method.

Client side code for grid.

```
var functionsMapping = {
        "abc": function (cellValue, opts, rowObject) {
            var tbl = "<table><tr><td><a href='/home1/About'><img src='" + cellValue + "' alt='a' /></a></td></tr>";
            tbl += "<table><tr><td>Name :aaa</td></tr>";
            tbl += "<table><tr><td>Phone :8888</td></tr></table>";
            return tbl;
        }
    };


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: "/home1/GetGridModel",

            success: function (data) {
                colMM = data.colmodel;
                ColNN = data.colN;
                for (i = 0; i < colMM.length; i++) {
                    cm = colMM[i];
                    if (cm.hasOwnProperty("formatter") && functionsMapping.hasOwnProperty(cm.formatter)) {
                        cm.formatter = functionsMapping[cm.formatter];
                    }
                }
                jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid({
                    url: '/home1/GetImageGridData',
                    datatype: "json",
                    mtype: "POST",
                    colNames: ColNN,
                    colModel: colMM,
                    rowNum: 4,
                    width: 700,
                    height: '300',
                    pager: $("#pager")
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetImageGridData(FormCollection frmcl)
        {
            int icol = 3;

            // it gives array of data
            object[] entity = this.FetchData();


            string[] colnames = new string[icol];

            for (int icount = 1, ilength = icol; icount <= ilength; icount++)
            {
                colnames[icount - 1] = "Col" + icount.ToString();
            }

            var eee = this.ToExpandoObject();
            object[] data1 = null;
            data1 = (from s in eee
                     select new
                     {
                         id = 1,
                         cell = GetColumns(s,colnames)
                     }).ToArray();

            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = data1.Count() / 4,
                page = 1,
                records = data1.Count(),
                rows = data1,
                userData = "aaa"
            };
            return Json(jsonData);
        }


        private object[] GetColumns(object s, string[] colnames)
        {
            object[] row = new object[colnames.Length];
            IDictionary<string, object> propertyValues = (IDictionary<string, object>)s;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (string col in colnames)
            {
                row[i++] = propertyValues[col].ToString();
            }
            return row;
        }
        public List<dynamic> ToExpandoObject()
        {
            var result = new List<dynamic>();

            int icol = 3;
            object[] entity = this.FetchData();
            string imagefieldname = "ImageSrc1";
            string[] colnames = new string[icol];

            for (int irow = 0; irow < entity.Count(); irow++)
            {
                dynamic e = new ExpandoObject();
                var d = e as IDictionary<string, object>;
                for (int collength = 0; collength < icol; collength++)
                {
                    d.Add("Col" + (collength+1).ToString() , entity[irow].GetType().GetProperty(imagefieldname).GetValue(entity[irow], null));
                }
                result.Add(e);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's really difficult to understand what you want to implement. [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is always a **string**. It defines simple rules which allows to encode information about object in the string. So it's unclear what you mean under "some custom json object which contains image source". Probably you should include pictures in your question and post more JavaScript code which explains your current state of development.

Comment: Do you want to display image and some other data in different row or different column

Comment: @Oleg: I have updated the question hope u understand what i want. and sorry for ambiguous question.

Comment: @Kris: no i want  show the image and info in every cell of grid. kind of thumbnail.

Comment: Can you share the data and the columnmodel

Comment: @Oleg : thanks oleg, your hint of json is always string, helps to put me in right direction to find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include any correct HTML fragment of data as output of the custom formatter. You current you use many open tags `<table>` and no `</table>`. It will break jqGrid. You can tor example use `<br/>` and `<hr/>` in the data fragments to have no `<tables>` at all or you can use have to fix the returned string by removing `<table>` from every string and appending the data with `</table>`.

**UPDATED**: the code which you post still generate wrong HTML fragments. The function `functionsMapping.abc` return string which contains **three** `<table>` and only **one** `</table>`.

Additionally your server code is very buggy:

- the data which you return from the server contains rows with **the same `id = 1` for all rows**. The value of `id` must be unique, so it must be different for different rows.
- the code of your server part place `userData` property instead of `userdata`.
- the value of `userData` property should be *object* and not just a string.
- you should add `gridview: true` to the list of jqGrid and use `pager: "#pager"` instead of `pager: $("#pager")` for better performance.
- the usage of `rowNum: 4` without specifying any `rowList` seems me not good.

If you want to send some custom information for every row you can place all as map by id inside of `userdata` object. For example if you post rows with ids `"i10"`, `"i20"`, `"i30"` then the `userdata` could be like

```cs
var jsonData = new {
        page = 1,
        ...
        userdata = new {
            i10: { ... }, // custom data for the row i10
            i20: { ... }, // custom data for the row i20
            i30: { ... }  // custom data for the row i30
        }
    };
```

Of case you can easy generate the value for the `userdata` as dynamic object and not static as in the example above. I wanted just explain you the idea.

The data from `userdata` you will see in the callbacks of `jqGrid` mostly as `$(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData")`.

Comment: Oleg thats fine, but i have updated complete code, my problem is, to show image and info in cell,  i used custom formatter where using cellvalue i get the Image Source but the values for info is not part of rowobject, so what approach i will take to achieve this.

Comment: @Meraj: I posted **UPDATED** part to my answer.